# Hash de algum campo do CakePHP2

Tags: php, cakephp, segurança, hash, sha1

Gerei algumas tabelas com scaffold do CakePHP2, tenho uma model chamada `account` e criei um setter e getter:

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = Security::encrypt($password);
}

public function getpassword()
{
    return Security::encrypt($this->password);
}
```

Só que o scaffold não usa esses métodos. Como faço para realizar o hash do campo  tanto na inserção como na visualização?

Answer (score 0):

Sugeria que usasses o [`beforeSave` para alterar os valores antes de serem guardados](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave), e ai podes fazer `Security::encrypt()` a password.

Que me lembre, o CakePHP2 não usa getters/setters dessa forma.

Para que precisas de fazer novamente o `encrypt` ao visualizar? Já vais ter o valor encriptado depois de fazer o `find`, no entanto, podes usar o [afterFind](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) para depois da query, alterar os dados conforme precisares.